# How do I keep elements aligned with "justify-content: space-between" if some of them have "display:none"?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/tmrczk/pen/RwayYXJ) here.

How do I change CSS styling to keep "LEFT", "CENTER" and "RIGHT" where they are if some of them have "display:none" applied to them?

```css
.rows {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 4em;
  align-items: center;
}

.row3 .l,
.row3 .c {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="rows row3">
  <div class="l">
    LEFT
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    CENTER
  </div>
  <div class="r">
    RIGHT
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `opacity : 0` instead of `display : none`.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use visibility:hidden instead of display:none as that will keep the elements' space while not showing them. It worked in your codepen.

Comment: @kevin rob yes opacity: 0 would do it but you cant then click on any element behind it while visibility: hidden allows this - depends on what the use-case is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `display` property to hide the element, use `visibility: hidden`. This will keep the visible elements from moving from their place in the layout.

You could also use `opacity` property to achieve the same result.

Using `visibility: hidden` will prevent the element from responding to pointer-events whereas using `opacity: 0` will not stop the element from responding to pointer-events. Use whatever seems more suitable for your use-case.

Following code snippet shows an example where left element is hidden while center and right aligned elements are shown in their correct place in the layout.

```css
.rows {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 4em;
  align-items: center;
}

.row3 .l {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="rows row3">
  <div class="l">LEFT</div>
  <div class="c">CENTER</div>
  <div class="r">RIGHT</div>
</div>
```